# Difference between using contextvars vs setting to Task.current_task()

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-contextvars

As I see there are two options in asyncio to share a variable.

The first is to use contextvars and the second is to set a custom attribute to Task objects (feels like a hack).

My question is what is the difference between these two options? Are variables set to the same scope (eg. contextvars run in the scope of Task.current_task()?

Comment: You might be overthinking this.  Python variables behave just the same way as they do in conventional program design.  You can pass them around as function arguments, make them globals, make them member variables in a class, attach them to objects as you suggest, etc.  Everything you already do for non-asyncio programs.  Context variables exist to solve specific and unusual problems,  I've written several medium-sized asyncio applications and have never used them.